Does anyone know how to create a route with dynamic path params?
We have migrated user-profile?userid=<id>  to user-profile/<userId>. With this migration, We can open this page if the user navigates through the homepage or other pages but is not able to open it if someone tries to open the page directly.

In Next.js 13, creating dynamic routes is straightforward and follows a similar pattern to previous versions. Here’s how to set up dynamic routes:
1. Directory Structure for Dynamic Routes
In Next.js, dynamic routes are defined by square brackets ([]). For example, if you need a route like /user-profile/[id], create a folder named [id] inside the pages or app directory.
Example Directory Structure:
/pages
  /user-profile
    [id].tsx
  index.tsx

